# How to plot additional statistics in boxplot for each group?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to see boxplots of combination of factors and [I was told to use lattice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18274873/684229) for that. I tried it and it looks like this:

[image]
But now I would like to also add an ANOVA statistics to each of the groups. Possibly the statistics should display the p-value in each panel (in the white below the e.g. "Australia"). How to do this in lattice? Note that I don't insist on lattice at all...

**Example code:**

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 300
country <- sample(c("Europe", "Africa", "Asia", "Australia"), n, replace = TRUE)
type <- sample(c("city", "river", "village"), n, replace = TRUE)
month <- sample(c("may", "june", "july"), n, replace = TRUE)
x <- rnorm(n)
df <- data.frame(x, country, type, month)

bwplot(x ~ type|country+month, data = df, panel=function(...) {
    panel.abline(h=0, col="green")
    panel.bwplot(...)
})
```

The code to perform ANOVA for one of the groups and to [extract p-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3366506/684229) is this:

```
model <- aov(x ~ type, data = df[df$country == 'Africa' & df$month == 'may',])
p_value <- summary(model)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `ggplot2`. First we can compute the p-values separately for every month/country combination (I use `data.table`. you can use whichever way you're comfortable with). Then, we add `geom_text` and specify `pvalue` as the label and specify x and y coordinates where the text should be within each facet.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
pval <- dt[, list(pvalue = paste0("pval = ", sprintf("%.3f", 
        summary(aov(x ~ type))[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]))), 
        by=list(country, month)]

ggplot(data = df, aes(x=type, y=x)) + geom_boxplot() + 
geom_text(data = pval, aes(label=pvalue, x="river", y=2.5)) + 
facet_grid(country ~ month) + theme_bw() + 
theme(panel.margin=grid::unit(0,"lines"), # thanks to @DieterMenne
strip.background = element_rect(fill = NA), 
panel.grid.major = element_line(colour=NA), 
panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour=NA))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Arun! But please how to remove the awful ggplot grid? :) BTW very elegant use of datatables! Didn't know they are so elegant!

Comment: better :) and if I want to get rid of it completely (so that it doesn't look like it is from ggplot :-))

Comment: BTW the label placement by `x="river", y=2.5` - isn't there something more flexible / independent of the actual coordinates?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "doesn't look like it's from ggplot". I've removed all default colours from the plot, if that's what you mean. `geom_text` requires `x` and `y` aesthetic. You can either create it yourself directly from your data in `pval` or you can provide it yourself. You can just add two columns `x` and `y` in `pval` and generate whatever values you want and give `x=x, y=y` in the plot.

Comment: Arun, I only meant to remove the grid *completely*. As for the flexible text placement - there must be something in ggplot! Even in the base package for example, you can place legend and specify the position e.g. like "topright"!

Comment: About the grid, please check edit. You can place the *legend* at different positions as you mention. But this is a *text geom*, *not a legend*. Have a look [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_text.html).

Comment: Arun, I didn't meant the bounding box (that was perfectly fine), I just meant the **[grid](https://www.google.cz/search?q=graph+grid&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&biw=1213&bih=700)** inside of each panel.

Comment: # Avoid ugly ggplot shading: 
theme_set(theme_bw()+theme(panel.margin=grid::unit(0,"lines")))

Comment: Thanks @DieterMenne, I've added your suggestion. However, wrapping with `theme_set` doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You can use the them_set as written, but it also can be set globally to remove the ggplot-hyped-background overall.